# Capturing touches on transparent UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I have an app that has a series of custom modal dialog views. Being modal I need to prevent users from interacting with items that are to the side of the dialogs (e.g. when the pause dialog appears I don't want users to be able to touch the buttons to navigate through the app). To make them modal I have a transparent `UIView` "behind" each of the dialog views to trap touches. This works fine except that there's a `UIView` animation that fades the dialogs up and while they're fading up the dialog views ignore touches.

As far as I can tell the problem is that if a `UIView`'s alpha is not equal to 1.0 then it ignores touches. Is there any way to have `UIView` with some alpha blending respond to touches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIView doesn't ignore touches unless its alpha is 0.0, or if its 'hidden' property is set to YES. Both of these settings make the UIView invisible.

I'd suggest using a modal view controller - unless there's some reason you want the other buttons to show. You would set a separate view controller for each modal view, rather than a transparent view. Then, use the view controller's 'presentModalViewController:animated:' method to control it.

Note that modal view controllers can be nested (one can call another), so you can have more than one chained together, as needed.

Comment: I just created a test project recreating the animation I have for the dialogs and indeed the view only ignores touches at 0 alpha so I'm not sure what the issue is. Unfortunately for me that doesn't resolve the problem but it does answer my question ;)

P.S. - Modal view controllers wouldn't work for these dialogs for a few reasons but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're animating the alpha of the dialog view, and you want the dialog view to support interaction during the animation, then you need to use the [`UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) option when you create the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I didn't know about that option. However, my problem is not that I want users to interact with the dialog while it's appearing, it's that I don't want them to be able to interact with anything *except* the dialog while it's appearing.